# Filtering HTML Table without using DataTable plugin

Tags: html, jquery, regex, filter

I have a HTML Table for which I am binding its tbody in jQuery.

I am trying to filter this table not using keyup function but with a click function on a list. Here I want to filter the table with exact match with the value I pass for the filter function.

For Example.

```
<table id="tableID">
 <thead>
   <tr>
   <th>Vehilce No </th>
   <th> Vehicle type </th>
   </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
   <tr>
    <td> 1547 </td>
    <td> Cranes </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> 5478 </td>
    <td> Crawler Crane </td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

In this Example, if I use

```
var value = 'Crane'.toLowerCase();
                
$("#tableId tbody tr").filter(function () {
$(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1);
});
```

this filter function it will return both the rows as both the rows contains value 'Crane'.

But I want to return the rows exact 'Crane' in it.

Please Note : I do not want to use DataTable plugin as I do not want textbox innput keyup function

Thanks in advance

Comment: you can decide not to display the search input box and that's it: you don't reinvent the wheel

Answer (score 0):

The issue is because you're looking for a match anywhere in the string. The simple workaround to this is to break the string in to an array of words using `split()`, and then find an exact match on a word within that array. Try this:

```js
let value = 'Crane'.toLowerCase();

$("#tableID tbody tr").hide().filter(function() {
  let containsWord = $(this).text().toLowerCase().split(/\b/).indexOf(value) != -1;
  $(this).toggle(containsWord);
}).show();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="tableID">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Vehilce No </th>
      <th> Vehicle type </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td> 1547 </td>
      <td> Cranes </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td> 5478 </td>
      <td> Crawler Crane </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response @Rory McCrossan. Your lines of code is returning the opposite result where I want to be filtered only 'Crane' by excluding 'Crawler Crane' in this case. Some more modifications to these lines of code will be more helpful.

Comment: In that case are you looking for the search term to only be found from the start of the string value? I can't see any other way you'd get the result you expect from the search term in your demo